# Is it webapp-root/META-INF or webapp-root/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF (Tomcat 7)

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat7

Unless I put META-INF in the root, context.xml along with the resources defined (queues, jdbc connection pool, etc) are not read correctly and Spring throws exceptions during start up.

Now I end up with two META-INF folders, I need one on the classpath (WEB-INF/classes/META-INF) due to persistence.xml.

Is is okay to have two META-INF's? I always configured resources in Spring's applicationContext so didn't notice before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it is all right. They both might have slightly different purposes.

`webapp-root/META-INF` is directory for metadata of the web application, which you can access via `servletContext.getResource("/META-INF/foo")`.

`webapp-root/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` is directory for metadata of java classes, which you can read via `getContextClassLoader().getResource("/META-INF/foo")`.